# How to combine a plot and legend?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to attach a legend to a plot in R.
I tried the following code ( taken from http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/ )

```
# Define cars vector with 5 values
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)

# Define some colors ideal for black & white print
colors <- c("white","grey70","grey90","grey50","black")

# Calculate the percentage for each day, rounded to one 
# decimal place
car_labels <- round(cars/sum(cars) * 100, 1)

# Concatenate a '%' char after each value
car_labels <- paste(car_labels, "%", sep="")

# Create a pie chart with defined heading and custom colors
# and labels
pie(cars, main="Cars", col=colors, labels=car_labels,
   cex=0.8)

# Create a legend at the right   
legend(1.5, 0.5, c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"), cex=0.8, 
   fill=colors)
```

However, this does not work really well. After the **pie(cars, main="Cars", col=colors, labels=car_labels,cex=0.8)** line , the plot is shown without a legend :-) .......Every example I see on the Internet seems to have the **legend** function after the plotting function so it seems very weird..............

When I try to execute the legend function I get

> legend(1.5, 0.5, c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"), cex=0.8, 
>   +    fill=colors)
>   Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex) : 
>     plot.new has not been called yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are off the coordinate system.  Try this instead

```
# Create a legend at the right   
legend("topleft", c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"), cex=0.8, fill=colors)
```

which produces the chart below:

[image: pie chart]

See the help page for `legend` for different placement options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the position `1.5, 0.5` puts it off the page.  Try

```
legend("right", c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"), cex=0.8, fill=colors)
```

After the `pie` function it appears with no legend; the `legend` function adds the legend to the current plot.

PS. You may also consider other types of plots.  Pie charts are notorious for being visually misleading.